# Leaflet polyline is not displayed with custom color

Tags: leaflet, geojson, polyline

I'm working on a project and I'm using Leaflet. From an object list extracted from the DB, I can currently display markers with custom icons. Now I'm working to display polylines from data I got in DB. With Javascript, I get the list and I arrive to display polylines but they are all blue where I want them to have differents colors depending on a property of the polyline.

```
var geoJsonFluxMatiere = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': []
};
for (indexfluxMatiere = 0; indexfluxMatiere < listeFluxMatiere.length; indexfluxMatiere++) {
    var tableauFluxMatiere = {
        type: 'Feature',
        properties: {
            'id': listeFluxMatiere[indexfluxMatiere].idFluxMatiere,
            'fluxPrimaire': listeFluxMatiere[indexfluxMatiere].fluxPrimaire
        },
        geometry: {
            'type': 'LineString',
            'coordinates': [
                [listeFluxMatiere[indexfluxMatiere].posXDepart, listeFluxMatiere[indexfluxMatiere].poxYDepart],
                [listeFluxMatiere[indexfluxMatiere].posXArrivee, listeFluxMatiere[indexfluxMatiere].posYArrivee]
            ]
        }
    }
    geoJsonFluxMatiere['features'].push(tableauFluxMatiere);
}

var layerFluxMatiere = L.geoJson(geoJsonFluxMatiere, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        if(feature.properties.fluxPrimaire == true){
            var polylineFluxMatiere = new L.polyline(
                feature.geometry.coordinates,
                {
                    color: 'red',
                }
            );
        }else{
            var polylineFluxMatiere = new L.polyline(
                feature.geometry.coordinates,
                {
                    color: 'green',
                }
            );
        }
        return polylineFluxMatiere;
    },
}).addTo(map);
```

Coordinates are ok and the polylines are displayed where they have to but it's like color's parameter is ignored.
Did I do something wrong ?
By the way, I'm sorry for my english if it is not perfect.
Thank you !

Raphaël

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `.geoJSON()`, you use the `style` option to style features. There are two ways to do it, and you will probably want to pass a function to the `styles` property that performs your check agains `fluxPrimaire`.  Here is an example from the [geoJSON Docs](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/):

```
var states = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": { "party": "Republican" },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[
            [-104.05, 48.99],
            [-97.22, 48.98],
            [-96.58, 45.94],
            [-104.03, 45.94],
            [-104.05, 48.99]
        ]]
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": { "party": "Democrat" },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[
            [-109.05, 41.00],
            [-102.06, 40.99],
            [-102.03, 36.99],
            [-109.04, 36.99],
            [-109.05, 41.00]
        ]]
    }
}];

L.geoJSON(states, {
    //this is where you will perform your check to change the polyline color
    style: function (feature) {
        switch (feature.properties.party) {
            case 'Republican': return { color: "#ff0000" };
            case 'Democrat': return { color: "#0000ff" };
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

In your case, you can try something like:

```
var layerFluxMatiere = L.geoJson(geoJsonFluxMatiere, {
  style: function (feature) {
    if(feature.properties.fluxPrimaire == true){
        return { color: '#ff0000' };
    }else{
        return { color: '#0000ff' };       
     }
  },
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I looked at the leaflet's doc but not the examples... I tried it and now it's working ! Thank you a lot, will up vote your answer when I'll can.

Answer (score 1):

The `pointToLayer` option of Leaflet GeoJSON factory is used only for `"Point"` type geometries.

For `"LineString"` (polyline) type, you can use the [`style`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#geojson-style) option instead. Note that it should directly return style options, not a layer.

Comment: I copy/paste what I used for marker... Thank you for informations, I see that I need to read a little more docs on Leaflet.